# How to check the on/off status of toggle button in Selenium Java?

Tags: java, selenium

Can anyone tell me how to check the whether the [toggle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Edf9v.png) is on or off using Selenium in Java.

Comment: Can you please share HTML code snippet for toggles ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the appearance of the button, you should probably look for an attribute like `selected=true`, `checked`, or `enabled`.

```
isSelected = driver.findElement(toggleSelector).getAttribute("selected");
```

If you want a more specific answer, you should post the HTML for the toggle when it is both checked and unchecked.